# iPhone 5s storage space

Tags: iphone

iTunes tells me that I have no storage space on my phone.  It is the music that is taking up space.  But I only have 145 songs on the phone that I have selected (3 playlists).  The phone says that there are 600 songs.  How do I get only the extra space back from the music I don't want on the phone.

Answer (score 1):

On your iPhone, navigate to Settings > General > Usage.

At the top of this page there will be a list of apps in order of how much space they use. You can use this to decide what to delete to make more room for your music.

You can delete apps on the home screen by holding down on them until they start to wiggle. Hit the little "x" on any app to delete it.

You can delete music by sliding it to the left in your Music app. Then hit, "Delete."

Answer (score 0):

I manage what is on my iPhone through my Mac desktop using iTunes.

Inside iTunes, with the iPhone connected, you can select which playlists are actually on the device and keep the rest in iTunes.

You'll wan to make sure the iPhone is fully synchronized with your desktop first.

HTH

Comment: That is what I am doing, but the phone has much more music that I have selected.  I don't know how to get that music off.

Comment: It should come off when you resync the devices if you properly selected the playlists. Where it can get confusing is that you have playlists, albums, sync all music, etc. I would suggest trying again and only try one playlist (or even one song) and then hit sync again. If this doesn't work, perhaps attach a screen shot of the iTunes page you're working from?